# UWP Print preview not updating after window resize

Tags: uwp

I'm currently developing an UWP app and using the `Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager` class to show the preview window. I have some controls which affect the result and I call `printDocument.InvalidatePreview()` to refresh the preview when user changes them. It works fine until user resizes the window. After that the preview will not be updated after calling `printDocument.InvalidatePreview()`.

It’s absolutely unclear what’s going on within `InvalidatePreview`, because the documentation is very poor and there’s no source code.

Does anyone know a fix or a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very simple demo to try to reproduce your issue but I cannot reproduce. I invoke the `printDoc.InvalidatePreview()` after the user change the print preview option, code as follows

```
  if (optionId == "PageContent")
  {
      await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
      {
          printDoc.InvalidatePreview();
      });
  }
```

And it worked well, it also worked after the app's window resized. It seems the `InvaliddatePreview()` will recall [PrintDocument.GetPreviewPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.printing.printdocument.getpreviewpage.aspx) event if you have subscribed it and the print preview will refresh. I uploaded the [demo](https://github.com/sunteenwu/Cprint) to github, you can download for testing and compare with your project to find differences. If it cannot resolved by compare differences, you can try to reproduce your issue on this demo and let us help solve again.

More details please reference:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app.
And the official sample:https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing

Comment: Thank you for attention to my problem.

Your code works and it helped me to understand the problem better. The pagination takes much time with my data (I have more than 10 pages) and that breaks the print preview in my case.

You can reproduce the problem in your app if you add `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait();` to the `PrintDic_Paginate` method.

Comment: I found I can reproduce your issue.  ‘Resize the window’ actually mean resize the print UI window, right? Resize the print UI will lead this issue. I will communicate it with my team.

Comment: Yes, correct. Resize the print UI window will cause the issue.